# Getting only matched record details?

Tags: apex, trigger

With the below code I'm facing a issue is it's getting all records from Integration__c with matching case fields but my requirement is  if I created a new case it will check with the matching fields in `integration__c` object records, only those matched record details will be returned. It means only one record details will be returned from `integration__c` object.

code:

```
List<Case> cas = Trigger.new;

List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,IntegrationAccount__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c WHERE In__c=true];

    for(Case c : cas )
    {
        for(Integration__c intObj:listAll)
        {
            if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__c == c.Account.name && intObj.integrationwith__c == c.IntegrationTo__c ){

                String name = intObj.username__c;
                String pwd = intObj.password__c;
                String url = intObj.URL__c;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Have you read up on the salesforce docs on SOQL? Your questions seem to be a bunch of tell me what to do for some of the fundamental basic items. We would rather help you Learn how to do this than just do it for you

Comment: @Eric here in for loop i matched the Case fields with Integration__c object fields .based on matching it returns all records from Integration__c object. but I'm stucked at if one case entered into a loop how to match only that case record from all records of Integration__c object. so that i pass that record details to the further process

Comment: I suggest you visit trailhead as your last question you were given the answer and since you did not understand it you made the same mistake here (comparing an id to a name). Not to mention you are not filtering your query. You have some fundamental learning to do. Being given the answers is not helping you. If you have questions as you go we will be here to help answer them so you can understand. Believe it our not there are two answers in this comment that if you read up on the fundamentals u will see easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirement I could understood what was matching fields are `IntegrationAccount__c` and `Integrationwith__c`. You could try something like this.

```
Set<String> accountNameSet = new Set<String>();
Set<String> integrationToSet = new Set<String>(); //Not sure datatype of IntegrationTo__c field. Modify set type accordingly
for(Case c : Trigger.new){
    accountNameSet.add(c.Account.name);
    integrationToSet.add(c.IntegrationTo__c);
}

for(Integration__c intObj : [SELECT Id, Name, Username__c, Password__c, URL__c, IntegrationAccount__c, IntegrationAccount__r.Name, Integrationwith__c 
                        FROM Integration__c 
                        WHERE IntegrationAccount__r.Name IN :accountNameSet 
                            AND Integrationwith__c IN :integrationToSet 
                        LIMIT 1]){
    String name = intObj.username__c;
    String pwd = intObj.password__c;
    String url = intObj.URL__c;
}
```